# Conditional data validation in wpf

Tags: wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo

I have 3 radio buttons and a text box.
[See the image for UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELGoT.jpg)

When user selects 'Phone' radio button I should allow to enter only numbers in the textbox, similarly the other cases email and name.
Email should be in correct format. and name should start with character.
How to do this in wpf?

Comment: are you using databinding in your textbox?

Comment: @ Albert , Yes I am binding the Text property of it to a property in viewmodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the next:

**The TextBox code**

```
 <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxWithValidation" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay,
                            NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
        <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="ControlWithError"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="ValidationSymbol" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Content="{Binding ElementName=ControlWithError, 
                    Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors), Converter={wpfValidationIssueHelpAttempt:Errors2ValidationErrorContentConverter}, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CommonValidationSymbol}"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
    </TextBox>
```

**The converter code:**

```
public class Errors2ValidationErrorContentConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var errors = value as ReadOnlyCollection<ValidationError>;
        ValidationError error;
        if (errors == null || (error = errors.FirstOrDefault()) == null) return null;
        return error.ErrorContent.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The validation symbol code(put this to the resource section):

```
       <DataTemplate x:Key="CommonValidationSymbol">
            <TextBlock Panel.ZIndex="1000" Foreground="Red" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Bold" 
                           Width="10"
                           FontSize="15" Background="#0000FF00" Text="!">
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" Content="{Binding }" Placement="Right"/>
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
```

**Here is my DataContext code**

```
public class MainViewModel:BaseObservableObject, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _text;
    private string _error;
    private bool _isMailChecked;
    private bool _isNameChecked;
    private bool _isPhoneChecked;

    public virtual string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Text);
        }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == "Text")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text)) return string.Empty;
                Error = string.Empty;
                return GetValidationResult();
            }
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }

    private string GetValidationResult()
    {
        //define your logic here
        if (IsNameChecked)
        {
            Error = "name is wrong!";
        }
        if (IsMailChecked)
        {
            Error = "mail is wrong!";
        }
        if (IsPhoneChecked)
        {
            Error = "phone is wrong";
        }

        return Error;
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { return _error; }
        private set
        {
            _error = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Error);
        }
    }

    public bool IsNameChecked
    {
        get { return _isNameChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isNameChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => IsNameChecked);
            if (value == false) return;
            IsMailChecked = false;
            IsPhoneChecked = false;
            Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }

    public bool IsMailChecked
    {
        get { return _isMailChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isMailChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => IsMailChecked);
            if (value == false) return;
            IsNameChecked = false;
            IsPhoneChecked = false;
            Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }

    public bool IsPhoneChecked
    {
        get { return _isPhoneChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isPhoneChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => IsPhoneChecked);
            if (value == false) return;
            IsMailChecked = false;
            IsNameChecked = false;
            Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Hi, I am not getting a call to the indexer method

Comment: Actually I have my OnpropertyChnaged(..) implementation in different class. Shall I declare indexer method in that class?

Comment: @mmrp5 where do you rise the PropertyChanged event? Can you publish your view-model?

Comment: public class NotifyPropChangedImpl : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        /// <summary>
        ///  event to handle PropertyChangedEventHandler delegate 
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    }

Comment: sorry i am new here .. so dont know how to post a class

Comment: @mmrp5 ok, never mind. you should implement the IDataErrorInfo inorder to get the call to the indexer. Here is the logical chain of the validation process 1.User input. 2. The Property setter. 3. OnPropertyChanged of the property. 4. Validation indexer call.

Comment: Hi, Its working fine if I enter wrong credentials , but I enter correct email address the red border is not going off. Is there any issue in my code ?

Comment: @mmrp5 can you publish your view model?